# how do I change format of Date using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to display date as 18-03-2016 using javascript datepicker.If I didnot mention any format it is displaying as 03-18-2016.How to display like 18-03-2016.[this is sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifSzf.png)

Comment: Please add the corresponding code to the question itself (as a text, not an image!).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"startdate",
        dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"
    });
```

Comment: It will print 18-MAR-2016 but I want in the format of 18-03-2016

Answer (score 0):

As described here: [enter link description here](http://www.easy400.net/jsdatepick/aboutit.htm)

you can add this

```
new JsDatePick({
 useMode:2,
 target:"startdate",
 dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d"
});
```